# Does a rogue need to Hide after every attack of a full round attack ranged?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, stealth, sneak-attack

Based on the answer from KRyan to my [previous question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/196434/does-a-rogue-need-to-hide-after-every-attack-of-a-full-attack-action-in-melee) about full round attacks done by a rogue hiding in plain sight I know that the rogue needs to roll for hide after every melee attack. so if the rogue did 7 attacks would need to roll 7 times.

Does the same rule apply if the rogue attacks with a ranged weapon?

(Reading the answer to [this post](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/38072/sniping-how-does-it-work) it seems that *sniping* from PH 76 is an obsolete rule that a character attacking with a ranged attack can chose not follow, especially because it would limit the character to only one single attack per round.)

The rogue hides in plain sight, is invisible and incorporeal.

note: (We use the **Rule Compendium** over the **Player Handbook**)

Comment: This appears to be several distinct questions. We generally prefer to keep question posts to a single distinct question, but this seems like multiple different questions about how multiple different features are interacting.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov edited and will ask one question for each of them.

Comment: Does something about KRyan's answer make you doubt or are you just being sure?  The only thing that makes me doubt is the fact you put "melee" in your other question and "ranged" here.  You do mention sniping here but so does KRyan's answer there.

Comment: @joedragons we read it through a couple of times but we don't understand the answer. Our understanding of the answer is "its like melee, forget about sniping as it is not a good option"  is this correct?

Comment: Voted to close in the category "needs details for clarity". What is the goal of a rogue to hide? To permit sneak attack? Stay hidden just to stay hidden? I suspect it is closer to second, based on edit history, but it would be nice, if you could state it in the question. Also, do you maybe need more details on sniping? Or is it mentioned just to say: "no, I don't consider it as an option"?

Comment: @annoyingimp reading the question that I linked we simply don't understand the answer. our rogue wants to do full attacks ranged while hiding. Should I phrase the question in: is "sniping" an optional rule?

Comment: @Digius As I read it, sniping only applies to ranged but otherwise the answer given applies to both melee and ranged.  Did you consider just leaving Kryan a comment asking for clarification over there?  IMO that's exactly what comments on answers are for.  I'm respectfully shocked you accepted that as the answer if you're still unclear.  Your change of question to what you proposed to "annoying imp" totally changes the question presented here in my mind.  So maybe it's just as well closed (for clarity/until clarified).

Comment: @joedragons i sent a comment in the original question related to ranged attacks. Waiting for a reply over there as I am not sure how should I clarify this question.